# Custom message on Laravel policy authorization

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, authorization, policy, laravel-5.8

In my Laravel 5.8 project I am implementing a reputation system similar to Stack Exchange's one: for example, users can reply to a discussion only if they have "Level 3" reputation.

I wanted to use Laravel's policies system to build the permissions logic like so in my DiscussionPolicy file:

```
public function reply(User $user)
{
    $result = true;
    if ($user->current_level < 3) {
        $result = false;
        //I want to inject a custom error message here
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Everything works, but users get a 403 page without any explanation, and I wanted to find an elegant way to tell them that they cannot perform that action because they don't have Level 3.

Can you please suggest a way to inject somehow this message, to show it in my custom 403.blade.php page? I've been able to do this by flashing a variable in the session, but I don't think it's elegant, I would like to use something like a MessageBag (Illuminate\Support\MessageBag).

LARAVEL 8.x : check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56473607/custom-message-on-laravel-policy-authorization/66076485#66076485).

Comment: I'd probably throw a `Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException` with a helpful message and let the exception handler show the correct view with the message. Using the MessageBag seems quite convoluted for relatively straightforward functionality to me. Bonus is that you can setup the handler very generically ( return view with message that's in the exception ) and your policy code becomes quite readable since you only need to throw an exception with a message.

Comment: Thanks @Loek! Since I am using policies, all the exceptions are fired automatically, what I am missing is how to interact with the exception that is automatically fired. If I have to handle the exception myself I am doing something that is not straightforward either. Maybe Laravel is missing something here?

Comment: Hmm, that's true. Knowing Laravel, it's probably possible but it's not in the documentation. A quick search leads me to the `deny()` function instead of the `return false`, maybe that's better? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55717806/4074200 and https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Auth/Access/HandlesAuthorization.html

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! If you post it as a reply, I'll mark it as a solution of my problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer was given in comments, put here for reference:

Laravel provides this functionality through the `deny()` function in the [`HandlesAuthorization`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Auth/Access/HandlesAuthorization.html) trait. The `deny()` function throws an `UnauthorizedException` but allows you to specify a message instead of throwing a plain exception.

Replace the `return false` with it and you can send custom messages to render in the exception handler.

Example:

```
public function reply(User $user)
{
    if ($user->current_level < 3) {
        $this->deny('Sorry, your level is not high enough to do that!');
        // Laravel 6+ requires you to return the deny(), see following line
        // return $this->deny('Sorry, your level is not high enough to do that!');
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You have to `return $this->deny()`, at least on Laravel 6

Comment: I've tried both `return $this->deny()` and `$this->deny` in my Laravel 7 application, but the custom message never gets returned in the response. Any advice?

Comment: According to the updated docs, nothing has changed since L6. Returning the `deny` should do the trick https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Auth/Access/HandlesAuthorization.html . Are you sure that you actually get the exception you expect?

Comment: @BakerStreetSystems because the error view is fixed to `__('Forbidden')` instead change it manually to `@section('message', $exception->getMessage() ?: __('Forbidden'))`

Answer (score 8):

I thought I'd add this answer as I arrived here searching for how to return messages from policy methods as the code I'm maintaining only returns `false` when an action is not allowed.

The [current documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#policy-responses) says to return an `Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response` instance from your policy method:

```
...
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;

public function update(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return $user->id === $post->user_id
                ? Response::allow()
                : Response::deny('You do not own this post.');
}
```

Comment: ``$this->authorize('create', new Reply)`` always return 403 status code even though I've just set a custom one in ReplyPolicy ```Response::deny('You are posting too much', 429)```. Is there any clean solution for this?

Comment: @AmirRezaM75 - It's probably best to post a new question so you can include the relevant code and give more of a description. If you comment here again when you have I can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
class DiscussionPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function reply(?User $user)
    {
        if(!$user) return $this->deny("Your access denied.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace your `return false` by an exception.

```
public function reply(User $user)
{
    $result = true;
    if ($user->current_level < 3) {
        throw new \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException(response()->json([
           'success'   => false,
           'message'   => 'Your custom message',
           'data'      => [your custom response data]
        ], 403));
    }
    return $result;
}
```